# Dynamic type assignment issue in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

Importing the following resource from other files, that cannot be changed, because of ownership constraints (I don't own it):

```
    //otherfile.ts
    //============
    export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
    export type Scalars = {
      ID: string;
      String: string;
      Int: number;
      AWSDateTime: any;
    };
        export interface SortOption {
          label: string;
          order: "asc" | "desc";
          key: string;
          id: string;
        }
        export type Asset = {
          typename?: 'Asset';
          updated_by?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
          license_plate?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
          length?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
        }
        export const SORT_OPTIONS: SortOption[] = [
          {
            order: "desc",
            key: "updated_date",
            label:"A",
            id:"A"
          },
        ]
```

This is the code that consumes the above. I own this code and have the freedom to change anything here.

```
//consumer.ts
//===========
    //import the above stuff here
    import { sortBy } from "lodash";
    type SortOptionKey = keyof Asset;

    
    export const getSortedAssetsByOrder = (
      assets: Asset[],
      key:  SortOptionKey & keyof Partial<Asset>,
    ) => {
        return sortBy(assets, (x) => x[key]).reverse();
    };
```

getting an error where the function is consumed in another file

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'keyof Asset'.
>
> result = getSortedAssetsByOrder(result, sortOption.key, sortOption.order);

What are my options in consumer.ts to fix this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] others can paste directly into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing without unrelated issues having to do with pseudocode or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the suggestion. I have simplified my code

Comment: Try pasting your code into an IDE like the TypeScript Playground and see all the errors that have nothing to do with your question (pseudocode like `...` and undeclared types like `Maybe`, `Scalars`, `SortOption`, etc).   Then fix them, and update the code here.  Also unless you want to make the question dependent on an untagged third-party library like lodash, you might want to remove your example code's dependency on it.    Or tag the question so that people know that it's about that.

Comment: What is `SORT_OPTIONS`?

Comment: Added SORT_OPTIONS interface for clarity and removed "..."

Comment: And `Maybe` and `Scalars`?  I guess I'll stop asking about this stuff and just disengage.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though some details are lacking, the problem is that `SortOptionKey` and `keyof Asset` are different things. `SortOptionKey` may have some values that do not exist in `Asset`, therefore, you should accept the ones that are in the `Asset`. It can be done by simply modifying the `key` type to

```
key: SortOptionKey & keyof Asset
```

which is equivalent to interaction of `SortOptionKey` and `keyof Asset`

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yes, that removed the error but I got the error where the function is consumed.

argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | "length"'. -at sortOption.key
  
  > 350 |     result = getSortedAssetsByOrder(result, sortOption.key, sortOption.order);

Comment: Are all the sort options used for `Asset`? If that's true then should change the `SortOption.key = keyof Asset`. Otherwise, you will need add some custom type guard for checking if specific `sortOption.key` is keyof asset.
For example:

`const isKeyofAsset = (arg: unknown): arg is keyof Asset => typeof arg ==="string" &&  ['array of keys of Asset'].includes(arg)`
I wouldn't recommend but you can also use `as unknown as keyof Asset`, though this is not type safe and should be considered only as last resort

Comment: I changed this

type SortOptionKey = keyof Asset;
Now getting error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Asset', when consumed

Comment: Can you include the code where you invoke the function? I meant that in the type `SortOption` you should change `string` to `keyof Asset`

Comment: result = getSortedAssetsByOrder(result, sortOption.key, sortOption.order);
SortOption is a common interface used by Asset and other features, so I cannot make it asset specific

Comment: Then I suggest adding the custom type guard which I mentioned in one of the previous comments. Something like this: `if(isKeyofAsset(key)) getSortedAssetsByOrder(result, key, order)`